# Delay a ready function() in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
//this code animates the divs to the left after every 5 secs
$(document).ready(function() {

    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
        $('.box').each(function() {
            if ($(this).offset().left < 0) {
                $(this).css("left", "150%");
            } else if ($(this).offset().left > $('#container').width()) {
                $(this).animate({
                    left: '50%'
                }, 500);
            } else {
                $(this).animate({
                    left: '-150%'
                }, 500);
            }
        });
    }, 5000);)
};​
```

In the above code, whenever the page gets loaded the `div` elements keep sliding every 5 secs. But there is a button in my webpage which, when clicked, moves the `div` elements to the left or right respectively according to the button clicked. But the problem is the auto animation and animation occuring on buuton click sometimes overlap. So whenever I click the button I want to delay the auto animation in `document.ready` by 5 secs again.

This is shown in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9FPBA/2). When you keep clicking on the "left animation" or "right animation" buttons, the divs overlap sometimes. So I just want to delay the auto animation whenever I click the buttons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call `clearInterval(refreshId)`, and then re-run your code to set up the rotation.

Here's a rough sketch of how you could do it. I'm afraid I probably can't provide more detail than this, but I hope it helps!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var refreshId;
    function startRotation() {
        refreshId = setInterval(function () { /* rotate stuff */ }, 5000);
    }
    function restartRotation() {
        clearInterval(refreshId);
        startRotation();
    }
    startRotation();

    var button = /* find the buttons that should restart the rotation */;
    button.click(restartRotation);
};
```

Comment: I appreciate your help but I am not that good with coding sir. Could you please be more precise. I mean could you post the code with my existing one. its a request.

Comment: And when I use the clearInterval(refreshId) it kills the auto animation completely. Only the button animations work. Auto animation stops.

Comment: I've expanded my answer; I hope the extra detail clears it up for you.

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/9FPBA/5/ Note how the code to start the animation was put into a function so it can be called multiple times. And calling it clears out any pending animation and starts a fresh one.

Comment: I cant thank you people enuf for the help. It worked thanks a ton!! This was bugging me since a long time. Thanks again..